# Git stash: prevent converting line separators

Tags: git

In my normal `core.autocrlf=true` repositories on Windows I had a file with `\n` line separators (intentionally). After saving as a stash and applying it later, it was changed back to `\r\n` which was a little bit unexpected for me.

How can I make saving and applying a stash not convert any line separator but keep the files as is?

Comment: Worth knowing: `git stash` works by making commits, so everything that happens with commits, happens with stashes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before stash , you can turn off the crlf conversion.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

You can turn it back after you apply stash.

Comment: ... or by invoking the stash commands with `-c core.autocrlf=false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.gitattributes` or `.git/info/attributes` to change CRLF handling on specific files. For example,

```
*.special text eol=lf
```

will always convert to `\n` in the Git repository. See [man gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) for more.

Comment: I don't want to change that permanently, I just want stash to keep what was there.